# How to estimate gasLimit of ERC20 contracts in web3.php project?

Tags: web3js, tokens, contract-debugging, gas-estimate, web3.php

I am using [web3.php](https://github.com/sc0Vu/web3.php) project in my Ethereum based project. A part of this project is sending ERC20 tokens, and in this regard, I need to estimate gas limit of transaction. For this purpose, I found the example below in the official documents of this project as below:

```php
$contract->at($contractAddress)->estimateGas($functionName, $params, $callback);
```

and I changed it to my own code like this:

```php
$gasLimit = 0;
$contract = new Contract($web3->provider, $contract_abi);
$contract->at($contract_address)->estimateGas('transfer', [
     'to'=>'0xa96Ce4C161271C797d979017821A278e1481eAfA',
     'value'=>1
   ], function ($err, $gas) use (&$gasLimit) {
         if ($err !== null) {
             echo $err->getMessage();
             return false;
         } else {
             $gasLimit = $gas;
         }
    }
);
```

After running this code, I receive this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: Please make sure you have put all function params and callback...
```

And I am not sure what are the required params in `$params` as the sample which is mentioned in this project. I tried to put something using documents provided for `estimateGas()` [here](https://eth.wiki/json-rpc/API#eth_estimategas).

May you help me please to solve this issue?

Comment: Function `transfer` takes parameters `to` and `amount` only. Transaction parameters `from`, `gas`, `gasPrice` and `value` are passed separately (i.e., as part of the transaction, not as part of the function call).

Comment: You're missing the transaction call object, as described [here](https://eth.wiki/json-rpc/API#eth_call). You should encode the function-call to `transfer` (along with your input to that function), and pass it in the `data` field of that object.

Comment: @goodvibration, I removed `from` in the code and received the same result after that in regard to your first comment. In regard to your 2nd comment, I have used the `$contract_abi` which is given based on the token user want to use. Do you mean anything else? Sorry, I'm new in Ethereum contracts and its related issues...

Comment: Read the documentation that I linked in the second comment.

Comment: @MohammadSaberi You are missing the methods parameters. `estimateGas('transfer', '0xa96Ce4C161271C797d979017821A278e1481eAfA', 1, [ 'from' => '0x1234143..', 'gas' => '0x200b20' ], function (...) { ... })` .

Comment: @Ismael, thank you so much. You solved my issue with your clear answer. I wish you had entered your comment in form of answer so I could upvote it ;-)

Comment: @MohammadSaberi You can add it as answer. I haven't tested it, I'm more a javascript so I'm not sure of the right php syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Try this example:

```
 $contract->at($contract_addr2)->estimateGas('transfer',
            $to_addr,
            1
        , function ($err, $gas) use (&$gasLimit) {
            if ($err !== null) {
                echo $err->getMessage();
                return false;
            } else {
                $gasLimit = $gas;
            }
        });
```